# App Stops when trying to play Video Ads

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My APP has video ads section where users can watch ads from admob when I pressed play button in the morning ads were coming and everything was working great but now when I click that same button app is crashing Below I is the details of what I got from logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: eelam.ellalan.rechargemafia, PID: 8570
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eelam.ellalan.rechargemafia/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation(IActivityManager.java:5675)
        at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:5739)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951470:182)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.d.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951470:216)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951470:76)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.c.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA@11951470:8)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzwl.onCreate(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
        01-06 15:51:34.704 1324-1324/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 218 ms
```

Comment: @Nilu Changing the target SDK to 26 from 27 solved all the issues Thanks for your Help Again...

Comment: happy to help you my friend enjoy codding